# jQuery: Why 2 ajax GET requests instead of 1 request?

Tags: jquery, get, history, jquery-tools

Why does [this page](http://jsbin.com/ogilo/3#http://bit.ly/cKnMc2) have two AJAX GET requests instead of one?

It has two requests [one](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax1.htm) after [another](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax3.htm), but *it must have just 1 request.* Editable code can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/ogilo/3/edit).

You can check the bug in the Firebug console.

Comment: On removing `initialIndex: 0`, http://jsbin.com/ogilo/4#http://bit.ly/cKnMc2 work well on all browsers, just unfortunately is casing a new bug for IE7, IE6 after giving `zero` GET request for http://jsbin.com/ogilo/4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On removing `initialIndex: 0,` [jsbin.com/ogilo/4#http://bit.ly/cKnMc2](http://jsbin.com/ogilo/4#http://bit.ly/cKnMc2) work well on all browsers, just unfortunately is casing a new bug for IE7, IE6 after giving `zero` GET request for [jsbin.com/ogilo/4](http://jsbin.com/ogilo/4)

Answer (score 0):

Your demo is combining AJAX-enabled tabs and a history-plugin.

It looks like the tab plugin is *always* loading the first tab and then loading a second tab if one is specified by the history.

The order of events is:

- Page loads
- First tab (aHW5jy) is requested via AJAX (1st GET)
- History plugin restores state from URL (sees: `#http://bit.ly/cKnMc2` in the URL, and then performs GET for cKnMc2)
- 2nd AJAX request completes, result is shown.

So, to summarize the issue, you need to determine which tab the URL is requesting prior to the Tabs plugin initializing the content for any tab.  It should just grab tab #3 if that's specified, whereas currently it grabs tab #1 then tab #3.

Comment: since you're using jQuery extensions from flowplayer, why not try researching if others have already combined these two functions successfully?

Comment: already tried, also I asked for issue from jquery tools author too

Comment: It looks like it's normal behavior with that library.  Their demo page with AJAX + History tabs shows the same behavior: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html#ajax2.htm

Comment: I post this bug also in http://github.com/jquerytools/jquerytools/issues/issue/187

Comment: fyi -- if jQueryUI is an option, then it looks like it supports specifying the initially selected tab via the 'selected' option.  Not sure if it works in combination with their AJAX tabs, but just bumped into it and wanted to mention it.